# change the android actionbar submenu text color

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-theme, textcolor

How to change the text color of submenu in Android? I customize the application theme and override the relative attributes, but it still doesn't work. My menu has two submenus, which are initially hidden, when clicked, it shows. However, the style of submenus can't be modified, while the title of action bar can. This question bothers me all the day, I almost try every ways I find.
This is my code!

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.classsignin.MainActivity" >

<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
    android:title="分享"
    android:icon="@drawable/drop_select"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    >
    <menu >
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/absent"
            android:title="请假"
            android:icon="@drawable/absent"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:title="刷新课程"
            android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
             />
    </menu>
</item>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarMenu</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">  
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>  
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarMenu" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">  
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item> 
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem">
   <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">  
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you will want to customise your `MenuItem`'s style by having the `android:itemBackground` attribute overridden with your custom `color/drawable selector` in your `style.xml` and as well a vtextColor` attribute to override.

In case your menu has also `submenu's`, then you will want as well to style the `header` title of the submenu, which usually is automatically with White background by overriding the attribute `actionBarPopupTheme` with your `custom style`.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/menu_popup_selector</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/SubmenuHeaderStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SubmenuHeaderStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**menu_popup_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color
            android:color="#655611"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And you will have something like those screenshots
[image: 1st Menu] 
[image: Submenu after click of an item in the 1st Menu]
(1st menu and then the submenu after clicking one item on the 1st menu - the pink header is my submenu header).

Just for you to know when I have the normal *menu without submenu* would look like this hierarchy views:

```
<menu> 
   <item/>
   <item/> 
   <item/> 
</menu>
```

and a *menu with submenu* as this example of hierarchy views:

```
<menu> 
   <item/>
   <item/>
   <group> 
     <item> 
       <menu> 
         item 
         item 
         item 
       </menu> 
     </item>
   </group>
   <item/>
   <item/> 
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

For material navigation view, you can change color and text appearance

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
.....
app:subheaderColor="@color/blue_700"
app:subheaderTextAppearance="@style/titleTextStyle"
...
/>
```